# how to construct core-plot multi-bar with variable segment count

Tags: bar-chart, core-plot

[condensed] Source at [InfoBarView.m](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8QzZhjxD4brWUZTbzluM0VKaEE)

What I want to see
[image]

What I'm getting
[image]

My plotData is an array of items:

```
- (void)generateData
{
    InfoBarView * barView = (id)[[self defaultLayerHostingView] superview];
    InfoController * controller = barView.controller;
    Group * group = controller.group;

    self.plotData = group.items;
}
```

Which seems fine to me and the plots are rendered as:

```
//  Create bar plot(s)
for (Item * item in group.items)
{
    static int offsets[] = { -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 };
    int segsCount=0;

    for (NSString * getter in @[ @"fldA", @"fldB",  @"fldC", @"fldD" ])
    {
        barPlot = [[[CPTBarPlot alloc] init] autorelease];

        NSLog(@"render:%lu '%@' field:%d %@", plotCount++, item.name, segsCount, getter);
        barPlot.lineStyle           = barLineStyle;
        barPlot.barCornerRadius     = 4.0;
        barPlot.barsAreHorizontal   = NO;
        barPlot.dataSource          = self;
        barPlot.delegate            = self;
        barPlot.identifier          = @{ kTarget : item,
                                         kGetter : getter },
        barPlot.barOffset           = @(offsets[segsCount]);
        barPlot.barBasesVary        = (segsCount++ > 0);
        barPlot.barWidth            = @(segsCount * .25f);

        [graph addPlot:barPlot toPlotSpace:barPlotSpace];
    }
}
```

But here's where I'm baffled; I'm trying to get 'n' bars, each with 4 segments. I'm trying to understand what my datasource should response with; currently:

```
- (nullable id)numberForPlot:(nonnull CPTPlot *)plot 
                       field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum
                 recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    InfoBarView * barView = (id)[[self defaultLayerHostingView] superview];
    InfoController * controller = barView.controller;
    Group * group = controller.group;

    NSDictionary * data = (NSDictionary *)plot.identifier;
    SEL dataItem = NSSelectorFromString(kTargets[controller.barDATAIndex]);
    SEL getter = NSSelectorFromString(data[kGetter]);
    SEL starts = @selector(fldD);
    Item * item = data[kTarget];
    CGFloat runs, value=0;
    id num=nil, data;

    //  First get which otpj block we're after
    data = [item performSelector:dataItem];
    runs = [[data performSelector:starts] floatValue];

    //  Now fetch its getter
    switch ( fieldEnum )
    {
        case CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation:
            num = @(index % group.itemCount);
            break;

        case CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip:
            value = [[data performSelector:getter] floatValue];
            num = @(value / runs);
            break;

        case CPTBarPlotFieldBarBase:
            //  Calc base by sum prior fields
            for (fpos_type_t fpos=Win; fpos < (index % 4); fpos++)
            {
                value += ([[data performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(kGetters[fpos])] floatValue] / runs);
            }
            num = @(value);
    }

    NSLog(@"numberForPlot:'%@' record:%lu field:%lu %@ = %@", item.name, index, fieldEnum, data[kGetter], num);

    return num;
}
```

I think the recordIndex should be 0..group.items.count; each of these bars will have 4 segments 0..4. And as my plot.identifier is the item object I can fetch what I need from there; first a sub-record data object. then a field within that data record.

I think my datasource should return
CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation: 0..group.items.count
CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip: the value for the seg
CPTBarPlotFieldBarBase: the starting vertical offset for the seg

Eventually, as to the bar fill, I wanted to take the items colors to derive a series of increasing darkness colors so that colors within the group would have the same hue.

So as you can see all I get is a blob; there should have been individual bar items each hopeful grouping as in my first image. For starters I'm just trying to get the segs one over the other -same width, but eventually do want the seg to vary in width to expose more of it.

---

Comment: There are six segments but only four offsets. You need more offsets in the array, otherwise `offsets[segsCount]` indexes past the end of the array.

Comment: Please show the rest of the graph setup code, the datasource methods, and some sample data. Also, please explain the purpose of the `group.items` array. I suspect you don't need separate plots for each one.

Comment: I think I solved my access problem, I just set the plot's identifier to a dictionary which details the item and getter of its value to fetch for the plot. I believe if I order of plot property, creation order is display order so plots to be partially occluded should go before those to be atop others. Just need to sort out the offset, width and whether I do really want stacking.